# Make useEffect only run when component is in view (i.e. scrolled down to that component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i have this code that updates a number from 2019 to 2022 but i want it to only run when the component is in view, meaning if they haven't scrolled to that part of the page the effect shouldn't run

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        setTitle(2020)
    }, 2000)
    setTimeout(() => {
        setTitle(2021)
    }, 4000)
    setTimeout(() => {
        setTitle(2022)
    }, 6000)
},  []);
```

at the moment it updates the value even when you haven't scrolled down to that part of the page, is there a way to make useEffect only activate when scrolled to that section of the page or do you need to do it completely differently?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var element = document.querySelector('#main-container');
    var position = element.getBoundingClientRect();

    // checking whether fully visible
    if(position.top >= 0 && position.bottom <= window.innerHeight) {
        console.log('Element is fully visible in screen');
    }

    // checking for partial visibility
    if(position.top < window.innerHeight && position.bottom >= 0) {
        console.log('Element is partially visible in screen');
    }
});
```

Snippet from https://usefulangle.com/post/113/javascript-detecting-element-visible-during-scroll. Paste your code to the part where an element is fully in view. Remember to query select the element you want to have in view first.

Comment: This works with JS but I'm not sure how I would implement that into React, on top of that useEffect would not work within an if statement. Are you aware of any way to just make useEffect run when a component is visible? Thanks either way though.

Comment: If you use the snippet above you can forego your wrapping function entirely and just use the timeouts.

Comment: You can use react way of accessing DOM nodes https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html . You'd still need to watch `window`, or it would be best to do so. A solution without `window` is possible too but that's a lot to write to properly explain.